# Onclick listener should call multiple intents?

Tags: javascript, android, android-intent, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a phone number field in my App. Currently I use `onclick` to tap and call a number, `onLongclick` listener to add the numbers to contact directory.

My requirement is on some event I want to share the phone-number through whatsapp,sms or any other sharing app installed on my phone.

How is this possible ?

1. What event/intent can I use? And what will be the code?
2. Can I generate a popup box only using `onclick` event and ask for choosing Add contacts, Call and Share intents? If yes what will be the code?

   [Code goes like this for call and copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alzpB.png)

Comment: Have you already tried anything yourself? Show the code that does not work to make it easier to help you.

Comment: @migg Actually i am not getting any idea how to execute. May be you can help .

Comment: You can do this using only onclick event, for example, but you have to show a context menu with the options the user has. Then check for the selected option to start the corresponding intent